# Build a positive Cartesian coordinate system in the space so that the $Oz$ axis is orthogonal to the unit triangle and goes through the centroid

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, rotations, barycentric-coordinates

Build a positive Cartesian coordinate system in the space so that the $Oz$ axis is orthogonal to the triangle defined by the vertices $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ and goes through the centre of mass.

The centroid here is $(1/3, 1/3, 1/3)$. The normal $\vec{n} = (1,1,1)$ is orthogonal to the triangle.

Am I just meant to multiply $(a,b,c)$ by a rotation matrix so that $Oz$ changes to $\vec{n}$?

Comment: What is $(a,b,c)$?  Also, note that such a new coordinate system is not uniquely defined as a variety of choices for Ox and Oy can span the plane of the triangle.

Comment: @Mathemagical $(a, b, c)$ is just a point in the standard coordinate system.

Comment: OK, why don't you just pick as second corrdinate, a vector $\vec{a}$ in the plane, say the one from the centroid to one of the vertices. Then your third coordinate axis will be along the cross product $\vec{n} \times \vec{a}$